# Error in invoking onClick() in included layout

Tags: android, data-binding

I am new to data binding. When I try to invoke a method from viewModel , I keep getting this particular error ,

`Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the proper callback class for android:onClick. Tried android.view.View but it has 0 abstract methods, should have 1 abstract methods.
file:C:\Projects\myapp\app\src\main\res\layout\content_details.xml
loc:73:27 - 73:69
****\ data binding error ****`

I've parse the 'viewModel' variable from both xml and from activity. It just don't work.
The method can be called from a text view in activity_details.xml which is the parent of included layout.It works perfectly. The error is getting from included layout only.
I've tried the other solutions ,those solutions just don't work for me.
any idea how to solve this?

included_layout.xml

```
  `  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout >
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.daniel.user.viewmodels.ItemDetailsViewModel"/>
    </data>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
    >
....
 <com.varunest.sparkbutton.SparkButton
        android:id="@+id/favBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageScrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:sparkbutton_activeImage="@drawable/heart"
        app:sparkbutton_iconSize="30dp"
        app:sparkbutton_inActiveImage="@drawable/ic_home_white_24dp"
        app:sparkbutton_primaryColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:sparkbutton_secondaryColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.updateItemFavouriteStatus()}"
        />
.....
</RelativeLayout>
</layout> `
```

this is my ViewModel.

```
   `    
    public class ItemDetailsViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
        public MutableLiveData<ErrorVO> errorVOMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        public void updateItemFavouriteStatus() {
            errorVOMutableLiveData.setValue(new ErrorVO("Clicked gg", 0));
        }
    }    
    `
```

This is my activity.

```
`
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_details);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ItemDetailsViewModel.class);
        binding.contentDetails.setVariable(BR.viewModel,viewModel);
        binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
}
   `
```

Comment: You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51842041/google-signinbuttons-onclick-doesnt-work-using-databinding, seems a similar thing. I think problem come because you are using custom button.

Comment: tried that solution before. It didn't work for me

Comment: Can you show us content_details.xml, where error is?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are not putting the parameter (View v) on the updateItemFavouriteStatus method:

```
public void updateItemFavouriteStatus(View v) {}
```

Comment: Tried that way before. It also get me the same result.

Comment: After adding parameter into function, what error you receive?

Comment: `Cannot find the proper callback class for android:onClick. Tried android.view.View but it has 0 abstract methods, should have 1 abstract methods.` still the same though

Comment: I think then you need to write your updateItemFavouriteStatus method in activity instead of viewmodel

Comment: If so, another variable representing activity would be needed to declare in included layout?

Comment: no need to declare anything in layout related to activity

Comment: so, like a normal onClick method declaration from xml? I see

Comment: Yes like a normal method